# How to receive data from Server in "Multipart/form-data" in iOS swift?

Tags: iphone, swift

```
func postRequestUsingDictionaryParametersImage(requestType : String, urlComponent : String, inputParameters : NSDictionary, completion: (result : NSData, httpResponse : NSHTTPURLResponse) -> Void, failure:(error: NSError) ->()){

    let accessToken : String = "Bearer " + (TNPAppData.sharedInstane.objTNPUserData?.accessToken)!
    let urlString: String = "\(kBaseURLString)\(urlComponent)"
    do {

        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(inputParameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
        let data = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)


        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = requestType
        request.HTTPBody = data
        request.setValue("application/Json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue(accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")


        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                failure(error: error!)
                return
            }

            do{
                let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                print("Response from Server :", dict)

            }
            catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }


            let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse

            print(httpStatus)

            if httpStatus?.statusCode ==  401 {

                // Make Request for New Access Token

                let str = TNPAppData.sharedInstane.objTNPUserData!.refreshToken

                let inputparameters = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + str

                print(inputparameters)

                self.requestTokenAgain2("token", inputParameters: inputparameters, requestType: "POST", refrshcompletion: { (result, httpResponse) in

                    do {

                        let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(result, options: .AllowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                        print("Response from Server :", dict)

                        let httpStatus = httpResponse as? NSHTTPURLResponse

                        if httpStatus?.statusCode == 400{

                            completion(result: result, httpResponse: (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)!)

                        }

                        else if httpStatus?.statusCode == 200{

                            let obj = TNPUserData(dictionary: dict)
                            TNPAppData.sharedInstane.objTNPUserData = obj

                            print("New Token Received")
                            print(obj.accessToken)
                            print(obj.bodyAccessToken)
                            print(obj.refreshToken)

                            // Now Call Get Details API Again
                            self.postRequestUsingDictionaryParameters2(requestType, urlComponent: urlComponent, inputParameters: inputParameters, completion: completion, failure: failure)
                        }
                        else{

                            // Go back to login screen

                            failure (error: error!)
                        }


                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print(error)
                    }

                    }, failure: { (error) in

                        print(error)

                })

            } else {


                if error != nil {
                    failure (error: error!)
                } else {

                    completion(result: data!, httpResponse: (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)!)
                }
            }


        }
        task.resume()
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to receive data (file) as Multipart/form-data in iOS swift. I am not able to achieve the same with above code.

Comment: The above code says it accepts multipart, but it actually just parses JSON responses. The key point is that server code doesn't generally send multipart responses and client code generally doesn't parse them. It's going to take a lot of work to do this. It's a really strange and atypical way of tackling this. If you want to send a file, just send the file. Why wrap it up in multipart body? If you really need to send additional meta data with the file, base 64 encode it and put it in JSON (or XML).